# Getting <p> from <ul><li /></ul>

Tags: dart, dart-html

I am currently working with Dart, and i have a minor problem, just something i can't get my head worked around right now.

I have a ul-List, within there are li-Element containing paragraphElements:

```dart
<li>
<p class="t-class">test1</p>
<button>Up</button>
<button>Down</button>
<button>Delete</button>
</li>
```

Now, with Dart i would like to read out those paragraphs from all the list elements. Whenever i do this with a querySelectorAll i only get a Array containing the letter 'p', not the content of the pElement.

Hope you guys can help me with this.

Code that only gives back 'p':

```dart
String test = toDoList.querySelectorAll('.todo-li').toString();
window.alert(test);
```

Comment: Please post the code that you tried that didn't work (is giving you `p`).

Comment: The problem is the `toString()` (see my answer).
`toString` is only for debugging purposes and does often return something like `Instance of SomeClass`.

Comment: Thank you guys, i think i will take a break and get this going in 30 minutes. my brain won't work right now...

Answer (score 1):

I tried it and it works

```dart
import 'dart:html' as dom;

main () {
  var ps = dom.querySelectorAll('ul > li > p');
  ps.forEach((dom.HtmlElement e) => print(e.text)); // or e.innerHtml
}
```